# PHP scripted download works when called directly but not with img src

Tags: php, html, image, file, download

Consider the following (simplified) PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("data/file.svg"));
header("Content-Type: image/svg");
$file = fopen("data/file.svg","rb");
while(!feof($file))
{
    print(fread($file, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
?>
```

Firefox correctly downloads the file "file.svg" when the URL of that php script is called directly. However when it is used via a HTML src tag like so:

```html
<img src="https://example.org/script.php">
```

Then Firefox reports "Could not load the image". The Network tab in the developer tools says that it "Transferred" 2.92 KB, but it says that the "Size" is 0 KB.
Why does it work in the first case, but not in the second?

Comment: i would use `readfile("data/file.svg");` after the header, should be all you need

Comment: The MIME type of an SVG is actually `image/svg+xml` not `image/svg`.

Comment: @Dagon As I said: it's a simplified script. In the real world I disabled caching and support much larger files and also ranges. readfile would use more memory (?) and I couldn't implement HTTP_RANGE.

Comment: no more memory, and it works for any size file.

Comment: Ooops, I confused it with file_get_contents (+print). PHP names are confusing...
With "larger files" I just wanted to point out the importance of memory efficiency.
So okay, you are right. But apart from that I still can't implement ranges and thus `readfile` is not usable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sherif already said in his comment I'm using the wrong MIME type. Replacing `image/svg` with `image/svg+xml` fixed the bug.